# Control the function call via Timer c#

Tags: c#, function, timer, onclick

Calling a function only after certain time interval although end user makes a request

```
public override void SendNotificationMessage(NotificationMessageRequest request)
    {......}
```

this is my function which will be triggered when there is a click action.

I want this to be called only at certain time intervals say 5 mins.Although the user makes a Request before the time interval...

I am trying to have a timer to serve my purpose but the problem is every time the user clicks then timer would start again..so that how could a function be controlled by timer

PS:I can not make changes in user application where the click is made

Comment: Could you post more sample code for SO to decipher?

Comment: Do you have multiple users who can call this function in your application?

Comment: yes there will be multiple users and once this function is called there will be some notification send to others ....so to prevent spamming i am looking for timely call of this function

Answer (score 2):

First you should add a Dictionnary to your class:

```
Dictionnary<int, NotificationMessageRequest> _notifications
```

Then when a user clicks on the button, you should execute this function: (or change the one that's executed now so that it looks like this)

```
private void PlanNotification(NotificationMessageRequest request, int userId)
{
    // or grab the userId from where you can
    lock(_notifications) // if needed ?
    {
        if (_notifications.Contains(userId)) return;

        _notifications.Add(userId, request);
    }
}
```

Then call this method on your timer event:

```
private void SendNotifications()
{
    lock(_notifications)
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<int, NotificationMessageRequest> p in _notifications)
            SendNotificationMessage(p.Value);

        _notifications.Clear();
    }
}
```

If you do something more or less like that you'll have the behavior you need.

Comment: let me do this for a single user...i am having a single user and he may make multiple request..First let me solve it and in future there may be chances of multiple users ...single user calls onClick() and thus function executes once and now eventhough he calls onClick() again the function should not be called

Comment: This will work for all users you want. But in this way, your function will only be executed every five minutes (for example). If the user clicks on the button and the timer hasn't ticked yet, it will execute the function later

Comment: +1 having the collection of `NotificationMessageRequest` is an easier and probably a better approach for the OP's case.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick solution I can suggest to keep a list of delegates with the method you want to invoke on each timer tick. So on user action you just add the method you want to invoke. If the parameters must be unique for each user call, you might do something like in the following code:

```
// This is the class handling the timer ticks
public class ActionExecutor : IDisposable
{
    private Timer timer;

    private IList<Action> actionsList = new List<Action>();

    public ActionExecutor()
    {
        // choose the interval as suits you best, or use 
        // constructor argument
        timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimerTick;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void OnTimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs)
    {
        lock(actionsList)
        {
            foreach(Action a in actionsList) 
            {
                a();
            }
            actionsList.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void AddAction(Action a)
    {
        lock(actionList)
        {
            actionList.Add(a);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // we must stop the timer when we are over
        if (timer != null)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
        if (actionList != null)
        {
            actionList.Clear();
        }
    }
    ~ActionExecutor()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

```
//handling user click in your application

void OnUserClick() 
{
    // built the specific notification request
    NotificationMessageRequest request = ...

    actionExecutor.AddAction(() => SendNotificationMessage(request));
}
```

In the code above, you must make sure you are using the same `ActionExecutor` instance where you handle the user actions. Notice the synchronization with the locks - timers usually run in separate thread than the thread adding the action. If you are speaking of a web application, then each user is running int his/her own thread, so multiple users at once will also add concurrency. Also, you may have to add appropriate error handling, as I have omitted that part for brevity.

---

**Update**

As suggested in comments, you might benefit from using a different collection than a list to hold the actions. It depends on the actual needs of your scenario.

Comment: I don't think a `List` of `Action` will be enough, it should be a `Dictionnary` or something else based on a userId. Otherwise a user can plan several executions of the same action without noticing it

Comment: @ppetrov  Yes, it might be a better approach if the OP wants to avoid duplication or otherwise manage the items added. I chose `List` for allowing executing the actions in the order being added.

Comment: This doesnot solve to my case since everytime the button is clicked the same function is only called and to that function i need some timer and your code could be used only when there is many functions

Comment: @Raghu, I skipped that part, because I wanted to emphasize on the storing and handling of the actions. I have edited the code to include a more complete `ActionExecutor` with the timer.

Comment: @IvayloSlavov of course my apologies! Didn't think of that, I was stuck with my loop scenario lol! I'll delete the related comments since they're not useful for the question

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in my current system. In my case, I'm batching data requests so that rather than making multiple calls to a remote service, I can combine them into one.

This is a high level overview of the system:

I have a CollatorClass that has one method MakeRequest()
Internally, CollatorClass has a Timer object that is initalised to null and a List of whatever objects hold your request details.

When MakeRequest is called:
The timer is started if it's null.
The details of the request are added to a list.

When the timer ticks over, the system reads the details of all requests from the list and takes the appropriate actions.
(Note that you may need to make use of lock in order to make all this thread safe).

If you want, you can also pass an Action reference to be called when the data request is actually performed. Not sure if this is necessary in your case though.

Let me know if you'd like more detail.

Comment: I am not gonna batch the request...i am gonna block the request and thus only timely calls would be implemented and others will not be executed at all

Comment: You could imlpement that simply by changing the MakeRequest method to only add a request to the list if the timer was null. (oh and don't forget to null the timer object at the end of the timer tick method.)

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer and set it's interval to a proper value. Then declare a field of type `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<YourMessageType>` (static if it fits) and put your message in the queue in the `OnClick`.

When timer ticks call `TryDequeue` and process messages.

Comment: yes i tried but everytime the onClick() is called and thus the timer is restarted..so my purpose of blocking a function will not be served

Comment: Why should the timer be restarted? If this is a web app make it a static field (and obviously your tick handler would be static too). Are you creating the timer every time OnClick is called?

Comment: no i am creating a timer for every onClick but i am not sure of how to implement a static timer field 
`Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start(); 
//business logic...stopWatch.Stop();
int timer=(int)stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;`

now timer variable is having some value and based on the value next request should be blocked(<5000) or allowed(>5000)

Comment: Dude! `Stopwatch` has nothing to do with a timer! See `System.Threading.Timer` or if your app is a WPF one `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`.

Comment: it will be helpfull if you share some links on Timer since i am not aware of it and simple code snippets would also be easy for me to understand